# ElasticSearch Scroll only return 10 records

Tags: elasticsearch

I used scroll to query ES, but I still got 10 records, my query as following:

```
curl -XGET 'http://10.0.0.5:9200/myin/app/_search?scroll=1m' -d '{
  "_source": "appAd",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "app.raw": "dt"
        }
      }
    }
   }
```

the following is the result:

```
"took":467,"_shards":{"total":24,"successful":24,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":760000} ...
```

But it only return 10 records although it hits 760000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to call the scroll API with the scroll_id returned in your query result to get next set of results. Continue to call until all results have been processed.

```
curl -XGET  'localhost:9200/_search/scroll'  -d'
{
    "scroll" : "1m", 
    "scroll_id" : "c2Nhbjs2OzM0NDg1ODpzRlBLc0FXNlNyNm5JWUc1" 
}
'
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: This did not work for me, only the initial call with "size" specified worked in subsequent calls.